# admin panel: system->configuration page not working

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, configuration, https

I am facing one problem with Magento 1.9. When I click on Configuration then it shows 505 internal page isn't working error. I don't know how to fix. Attached is the screenshot. If any file needed from my side please request in comment box.

Error log:

```
[18-Oct-2020 14:57:53 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract::setRenderer() must implement interface Varien_Data_Form_Element_Renderer_Interface, instance of Pixlogix_Shippingavailability_Block_Adminhtml_System_Configuration_Implementation given, called in /home/lxc8uxjzilec/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php on line 438 and defined in /home/lxc8uxjzilec/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Form/Element/Abstract.php:164
Stack trace:
#0 /home/lxc8uxjzilec/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php(438): Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract->setRenderer(Object(Pixlogix_Shippingavailability_Block_Adminhtml_System_Configuration_Implementation))
#1 /home/lxc8uxjzilec/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php(229): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form->initFields(Object(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#2 /home/lxc8uxjzilec/public_html/app/ in /home/lxc8uxjzilec/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Form/Element/Abstract.php on line 164
```

[image].

Comment: Hello Salman, would you mind updating your post with the most recent lines of your var/log/exception.log?

Comment: Yes adding error log.

Comment: Please confirm is it correct.

Answer (score 0):

I'm missing some information about what you are trying to accomplish, but from context, it appears that you are looking to add a new form to the Magento Admin Panel.

The error that you are getting is that your new form is not implementing the `Varien_Data_Form_Element_Renderer_Interface`.  Interfaces are like a promise, they allow us to write extensions and new functionality the integrates well with the core functionality.

`Pixlogix_Shippingavailability_Block_Adminhtml_System_Configuration_Implementation` appears to be from an extension, you likely need to write a wrapper module around it for to use it's functionality.

Comment: Pixlogix_Shippingavailability is a magento extension I have added successfully, but today I have add one more extension & after that this error comes.

Comment: Please tell the solution how to fix. Suggest solution in detail because I am new to magento.

Comment: Hi @thisischuck how to fix this?